# Cloudformation error in EKS NodeGroup: Instances failed to join the kubernetes cluster

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-eks

So, I'm trying to create a VPC, EKS Cluster and a Nodegroup through the following template, and I'm encountering the following error for the Nodegroup:

> Resource handler returned message: "[Issue(Code=NodeCreationFailure, Message=Instances failed to join the kubernetes cluster, ResourceIds=[i-01e2bc499c53b0b40, i-0e2aca2058a6f0192])] (Service: null, Status Code: 0, Request ID: null)" (RequestToken: b376f260-d21e-cba9-f0e2-5f01c8f1d374, HandlerErrorCode: GeneralServiceException)

I have figured that there is some issue when the Nodegroup tries to join the cluster, but when I build everything else through the template apart from the Nodegroups, and then I create the Nodegroup manually through the AWS Console, it joins the cluster without any issue.

Any ideas? Here is the template:

PS: I have pre-created the IAM roles and they work correctly

```
Parameters:
  EnvironmentName:
    Description: An environment name that is prefixed to resource names
    Type: String
    Default: test-cloudformation

  VpcCIDR:
    Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for this VPC
    Type: String
    Default: 10.192.0.0/16

  PublicSubnet1CIDR:
    Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for the public subnet in the first Availability Zone
    Type: String
    Default: 10.192.10.0/24

  PublicSubnet2CIDR:
    Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for the public subnet in the second Availability Zone
    Type: String
    Default: 10.192.11.0/24

  PrivateSubnet1CIDR:
    Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for the private subnet in the first Availability Zone
    Type: String
    Default: 10.192.20.0/24

  PrivateSubnet2CIDR:
    Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for the private subnet in the second Availability Zone
    Type: String
    Default: 10.192.21.0/24

Resources:
  VPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: !Ref VpcCIDR
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName

  InternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName

  InternetGatewayAttachment:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
      VpcId: !Ref VPC

  PublicSubnet1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs '' ]
      CidrBlock: !Ref PublicSubnet1CIDR
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${EnvironmentName} Public Subnet (AZ1)

  PublicSubnet2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 1, !GetAZs  '' ]
      CidrBlock: !Ref PublicSubnet2CIDR
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${EnvironmentName} Public Subnet (AZ2)

  PrivateSubnet1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs  '' ]
      CidrBlock: !Ref PrivateSubnet1CIDR
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: false
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${EnvironmentName} Private Subnet (AZ1)

  PrivateSubnet2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 1, !GetAZs  '' ]
      CidrBlock: !Ref PrivateSubnet2CIDR
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: false
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${EnvironmentName} Private Subnet (AZ2)

  NatGateway1EIP:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    DependsOn: InternetGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc

  NatGateway2EIP:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    DependsOn: InternetGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc

  NatGateway1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NatGateway
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt NatGateway1EIP.AllocationId
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet1

  NatGateway2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NatGateway
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt NatGateway2EIP.AllocationId
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet2

  PublicRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${EnvironmentName} Public Routes

  DefaultPublicRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: InternetGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway

  PublicSubnet1RouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet1

  PublicSubnet2RouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet2


  PrivateRouteTable1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${EnvironmentName} Private Routes (AZ1)

  DefaultPrivateRoute1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable1
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NatGatewayId: !Ref NatGateway1

  PrivateSubnet1RouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable1
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnet1

  PrivateRouteTable2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${EnvironmentName} Private Routes (AZ2)

  DefaultPrivateRoute2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable2
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NatGatewayId: !Ref NatGateway2

  PrivateSubnet2RouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable2
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnet2

  EKSClusterSG:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup"
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: "Security Group for EKS Nodes"
      VpcId: !Ref VPC 
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 22
          ToPort: 22
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0 # Adjust the CIDR to limit access as needed
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - IpProtocol: "-1"
          FromPort: 0
          ToPort: 0
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0 # Allow all outbound traffic
      Tags:
        - Key: "Name"
          Value: "EKSClusterSG"

  MyEKSCluster:
    Type: "AWS::EKS::Cluster"
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub "${EnvironmentName}-eks-cluster"
      RoleArn: "arn:aws:iam::0000000000:role/EKS"
      Version: "1.28" # Specify the desired Kubernetes version
      ResourcesVpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds: 
          - !Ref EKSClusterSG
        SubnetIds: 
          - !Ref PrivateSubnet1
          - !Ref PrivateSubnet2
        EndpointPublicAccess: true
        EndpointPrivateAccess: true

  CoreDNSAddon:
    Type: AWS::EKS::Addon
    Properties:
      AddonName: coredns
      ClusterName: !Ref MyEKSCluster
      AddonVersion: v1.10.1-eksbuild.6  # Specify the desired version compatible with your EKS cluster
      ResolveConflicts: OVERWRITE

  KubeProxyAddon:
    Type: AWS::EKS::Addon
    Properties:
      AddonName: kube-proxy
      ClusterName: !Ref MyEKSCluster
      AddonVersion: v1.28.1-eksbuild.1  # Specify the desired version compatible with your EKS cluster
      ResolveConflicts: OVERWRITE

  VpcCniAddon:
    Type: AWS::EKS::Addon
    Properties:
      AddonName: vpc-cni
      ClusterName: !Ref MyEKSCluster
      AddonVersion: v1.14.1-eksbuild.1  # Specify the desired version compatible with your EKS cluster
      ResolveConflicts: OVERWRITE

  EKSNodeGroup:
    Type: "AWS::EKS::Nodegroup"
    Properties:
      ClusterName: !Ref MyEKSCluster # This references your EKS Cluster defined above
      NodegroupName: !Sub "${EnvironmentName}-eks-nodegroup"
      NodeRole: "arn:aws:iam::0000000000:role/EKSworkers" # Replace with your Node IAM role ARN
      Subnets: 
        - !Ref PrivateSubnet1 # Replace with your actual private subnet logical IDs
        - !Ref PrivateSubnet2
      ScalingConfig:
        DesiredSize: 2
        MinSize: 1
        MaxSize: 3
      InstanceTypes:
        - "t3.micro"
      DiskSize: 10
      RemoteAccess: # Optional: Only necessary if you need to SSH into the nodes
        Ec2SshKey: "test-private" # Replace with your actual key pair name
        SourceSecurityGroups: 
          - !Ref EKSClusterSG
      Labels:
        node-role.kubernetes.io/worker: "worker"
      AmiType: AL2_x86_64
```